# How to improve this long angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, angularjs

I found my angularjs controller is pretty long, and it's a little out of control. Here is an example of my code (with coffeescript):

https://gist.github.com/4683847

(Since it has 139 lines, I think it's better to paste it to gist)

The methods are basically about CRUD, since there is a tree, a table, 3 forms there.

Could you give me some advises about improving it?

Answer (score 4):

Extract as much as you can to services.  That's the best practice in keeping your controllers lean.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you take a look at the corresponding html.
Start by grouping the controller code based on what chunks of html they affect.

Then extract them into a separate controller and add that controller to the corresponding root element of those chunks.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking of this. I will check if I can separate them into several controllers